# Why php extension is not compiled in shared library?

Tags: php, gcc, cygwin, pear

I trying to install latest version of  zip : http://pecl.php.net/package/zip

I tried to do that in different ways :

```
//first case:
pecl install zip-1.12.4

//second case:
wget http://pecl.php.net/package/zip/1.12.4
tar xzf zip-1.12.4
cd  ./zip-1.12.4

phpize
./configure --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-zip 
--with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config
make & make install
```

But in both cases i have the same result :  two files zip.a & zip.la instead zip.so

Commands like :

```
 //Building Shared Library from static Library

 gcc -shared -o zip.so -Wl,--whole-archive zip.a
 ld -shared -o zip.so --whole-archive zip.a
```

Are unsuccessful , several errors from output :

zip.a(php_zip.o): In function `zm_info_zip':
/tmp/pear/install/zip/php_zip.c:3155: undefined reference to`php_info_print_table_start'
/tmp/pear/install/zip/php_zip.c:3157: undefined reference to `php_info_print_table_row'
/tmp/pear/install/zip/php_zip.c:3158: undefined reference to`php_info_print_table_row'
/tmp/pear/install/zip/php_zip.c:3159: undefined reference to `php_info_print_table_row'
/tmp/pear/install/zip/php_zip.c:3160: undefined reference to`php_info_print_table_row'
zip.a(php_zip.o): In function `zm_shutdown_zip':
/tmp/pear/install/zip/php_zip.c:3144: undefined reference to`zend_hash_destroy'
/tmp/pear/install/zip/php_zip.c:3145: undefined reference to `php_unregister_url_stream_wrapper'

Any ideas how to fix that problem ?
 My working envarionment : Cygwin (under WinXP) and PHP + MySQL + nginx (under Cygwin of course)

Comment: The `--with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config` is suspicious.  Did you build this php yourself?

Comment: php-config is not php.ini .Is a simple shell script for obtaining information about the installed PHP configuration. http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php-config.php . Yes , i build php by myself.

Comment: PHP requires a number of patches to work correctly on Cygwin.  I suggest removing your self-built PHP and installing the `php` packages from [Cygwin Ports](http://cygwinports.org/) instead.